# Settings Class in Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have a Settings.cs class that exposes some Static properties. Those properties are read-only. This class reside in a seperate DLL than the website.

On the application start, I need to initialize the Settings.cs class and populate the Static properties with values. This shall be done once per Application Start.

I am hooking to the Application_Start event in the Web Application. How can I access those "private" Static properties on the Settings.cs class (residing in a separate DLL)?

I have one option which is let the Settings.cs class populate itself. But again I need to do so once per application start.

Is there a design pattern to handle such a case?

Thank you
regards

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Settings
{
    const string SettingPath = "Settings";
    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            var result = HttpContext.Application[SettingPath] as Settings;
            if (result == null)
            {
                var result = new Settings();
                HttpContext.Current.Application[SettingPath] = result;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private Settings()
    {
        // Load properies here
    }

    // Properties Here
}
```

And if you need to save Settings only per Session - then use HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionSetting"]

Comment: The situation is different:

Settings.cs resides in DLL-1
Inside Application_Start event, I need to fill the properties of class Settings. I am not after putting Settings in Application object.


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than programmatically setting the settings from the `Application_Start` event, instead have the settings specified declaratively in `Web.config`. The `Settings` class would then read and return these values from `Web.config`.

It would go something like this... in `Web.config` you could define the values for your settings in the `<appSettings />` section:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Setting1" value="..." />
        <add key="Setting2" value="..." />
        ...
        <add key="SettingN" value="..." />
    </appSettings>

    ...
</configuration>
```

Of course, rather than `Setting1`, `Setting2`, and so on, you would use more descriptive names for your settings.

In your `Settings` class your code would look as follows:

```
using System.Configuration;

public class Settings
{
    public int Setting1
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManage.AppSettings["Setting1"]);
        }
    }

    public string Setting2
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManage.AppSettings["Setting1"];
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that to read a value in `<appSettings>` you use `ConfigurationManage.AppSettings["settingName"]`. This returns the `value` of the named app setting as a string. So if certain properties are integers, booleans, or other types, you'd need to convert them accordingly as I did with `Setting1` above.

For more information on using the `<appSettings>` section, see [AppSettings in Web.config](http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx).

Happy Programming!

Comment: Hi Scott, Let me explain what I am after,maybe it'll be clearer.I have a settings.cs class contains properties of type "Interfaces".I'm using Unity to define my default implementations of those interfaces. I need to initialize the settings.cs once at the application_start, initialize means resolve the interface implementation. However, I have a bootstrapper hooked into application_start, that does several things then resolves the objects. What I want is to keep the properties RO properties,however be able to populate it once and not at every further request to improve perf. thanks